# I am trying to create a flight widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, settimeout

```
let mainid = document.getElementById("main_id");

function createcards(txt) {
  let cards = document.createElement("div");
  cards.classList.add("ex-1");
  cards.textContent = txt;
  return cards;
}

function addElements(parent, children) {

    children.forEach((e) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        parent.appendChild(e); 
      }, 1000);
 
    });
  
}

items = [
  createcards(1),
  createcards(2),
  createcards(3),
  createcards(4),
  createcards(5),
];

addElements(mainid, items);
```

I want to append each child one by one. I meant by changing the speed of setTimeout. I tried doing it using for loop but it's not working as expected. please anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem you a bit misunderstanding about the eventloop and how setTimeout work. Your code will delay 5 function, each 1000ms and then run those at the same time. For more you can check out this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&ab_channel=JSConf)

I tried with setInterval instead, you can check it out to see if it fit your problem

```js
let mainid = document.getElementById("main_id");

function createcards(txt) {
  let cards = document.createElement("div");
  cards.classList.add("ex-1");
  cards.textContent = txt;
  return cards;
}

function addElements(parent, children) {
  const interval = setInterval(item => {
    if (!children.length) {
      clearInterval(interval)
      return
    }
    parent.appendChild(children[0])
    children.shift()
  }, 1000)
}


items = [
  createcards(1),
  createcards(2),
  createcards(3),
  createcards(4),
  createcards(5),
];

addElements(mainid, items);
```

```html
<div id="main_id" />
```

Comment: Thankyou thanks a lot . This was the exact answer I was looking for. It loops everything one by one. You made my day .

Comment: Ohh sure I will .

Comment: I think I have to learn more about event loop and setTimeout is there any way to contact you for further help other than here. I meant any social media.

Comment: I think you can join the Discord Javascript Mastery (I have just found), there will be more people to help other than me

Answer (score 1):

You have to create immediately-invoked function expression [(IIFE)](https://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to create a closure around `setTimeout`.

```js
let mainid = document.getElementById("main_id");

function createcards(txt) {
  let cards = document.createElement("div");
  cards.classList.add("ex-1");
  cards.textContent = txt;
  return cards;
}

function addElements(parent, children) {
    children.forEach((e, i) => {
      (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() { parent.appendChild(e); }, i * 1000);
      })(i);
    });
}

items = [
  createcards(1),
  createcards(2),
  createcards(3),
  createcards(4),
  createcards(5),
];

addElements(mainid, items);
```

```html
<div id="main_id" />
```

Comment: Thankyou @Ahmad Faraz for taking your time to answer my question. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, using setTimeout as you wish. Here what I changed is use `for ... of` instead of `forEach`. `forEach` will not work with async function as I just discovered when I try to solve your question. Ref: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

```js
let mainid = document.getElementById("main_id");

function createcards(txt) {
  let cards = document.createElement("div");
  cards.classList.add("ex-1");
  cards.textContent = txt;
  return cards;
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function addElements(parent, children) {
  for (let e of children) {        
    await sleep(1000);
    parent.appendChild(e); 
  }
}

items = [
  createcards(1),
  createcards(2),
  createcards(3),
  createcards(4),
  createcards(5),
];

addElements(mainid, items);
```

```html
<div id="main_id" />
```

Comment: Wow its works amazing the for of loop is great cool nice work . Thankyou .